# What sites offer free, quality web site design templates?

Tags: css, templates

Let's aggregate a list of free quality web site design templates. There are a million of these sites out there, but most are repetitive and boring.

I'll start with [freeCSStemplates.org](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/)

I also think other sites should follow some sort of standards, for example here are freeCSStemplates standards

- Released for FREE under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 license
- Very lightweight in terms of images
- Tables-free (ie. they use no tables for layout purposes)
- W3C standards compliant and valid (XHTML Strict)
- Provided with public domain photos, generously provided by PDPhoto.org and Wikimedia Commons

Comment: I edited in a comma in the title.  The difference between "free quality" and "free, quality" is subtle but significant.  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out:

- [Open Source Web Designs](http://www.oswd.org/)
- [CSS Remix](http://cssremix.com/)
- [Best Web Gallery](http://bestwebgallery.com/)
- [CSS Based](http://www.cssbased.com/)
- [CSS Beauty](http://www.cssbeauty.com/gallery/)
- [CSS Genius](http://www.my3w.org)

Comment: Only this website have modern css design [my3w](https://my3w.org/)

Comment: How about https://freetemplateshtml.com/ ?

Comment: Explore latest themes, designs and automation scripts from all envanto platforms;-
Freebeats - Crafting Your Vision (https://freebeats.space/)

Answer (score 3):

[The Open Design Community](http://www.opendesigns.org/) is a great resource.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.csszengarden.com/

The images are not Creative Commons, but the CSS is.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for [Zen garden.](http://www.csszengarden.com/)

I like the resources at [inobscuro.com](http://inobscuro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.opensourcetemplates.org/ has nice designs, just not enough selection.